# Matching up 2 fields with differing Character lengths, substr? Padding?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, padding, substr

I need to be able to write a SQL to match customerid where the # of characters differs between tables.  As you will see below,  table 1 has the CustomerId with no padding (# of characters may differ, as shown within the example).  Table 2 has a specific format of '0001' + 0 padding to make the field a total of 30 characters.

So, if I needed to write SQL for this, for table1 CustomerIds, would this be some type of substring?

Example:.
Table1 has customerid as '123456'. 
Table 2 has customerid as '000100000000000000000000123456'

Example 2:
Table 1 has customerid as '98765432'
Table 2 has customerid as '000100000000000000000099765432'

Comment: In the second example, do you mean it is **NOT** the same customer? '98...' does not match '99...' as you have in the longer string. Or is that a typo?

Comment: Yes we can either lpad or sub string. personally I prefer Lpad.  we can do it like 
 '0001'||lpad(columnname,'0',26)

Answer (score 3):

You should pad the value from the table1 with 0001 and zeroes until it is 30 characters and then use that to compare.

```
where '0001'||lpad(columnname,'0',26) = columnname2
```

Comment: I believe the total number of characters, including the 0001, must be 30; so the LPAD should be to 26 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
........
where table2.customerID like '%' || table1.customerID
```

`like` is really a misnomer, it means "equals". '%' will match an arbitrary string, of any length (zero or more).

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` should  definitely a good option.

One more way, assuming that the columns contain only numeric characters, you could use:-

```
ON ( TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(tab2.customerid,5)) = tab1.customerid )
```

Adding a function based `INDEX` on `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(tab1.customerid,5)` **may** speed up the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use ltrim function for it like query below just trimming off 0s or 1s from table2's customerid:

```
   select * from ns_table2 a,ns_table3 b where 
   ltrim(b.val1,'01')=ltrim(a.val1,'01') ;
```

sample input:

```
create table ns_table2(val1 varchar(30),val2 varchar(30));
create table ns_table3(val1 varchar(30),val2 varchar(30));

insert into ns_table2 values('123456','table2');
insert into ns_table2 values('98765432','table2');

insert into ns_table3 values('000100000000000000000000123456','table3');
insert into ns_table3 values('000100000000000000000098765432','table3');
select * from ns_table2 a,ns_table3 b where 
ltrim(b.val1,'01')=ltrim(a.val1,'01') ;
```

sample output:

```
123456      table2  000100000000000000000000123456  table3
98765432    table2  000100000000000000000098765432  table3
```